# scp in Expect script works for few files but not for many files

Tags: remote-access, expect, file-transfer, scp

I wrote a bash code to send files to a sever computer from my remote laptop. I used 'scp' command and wrote it on a bash script to bypass entering a password every time I ran it.

```
expect <<EOF
spawn scp -P 1111 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r /Users/Desktop/sync_mac user@192.111.111.101:/home/folder
expect "password:"
        send "11111\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

However, the problem is when I ran the bash script on the terminal, it seemed like working well but suddenly failed sending files without any sign of warnings.(Especially for the case of sending a large number of files or a large size of file, it was okay for the case of a small number and a small size)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you run `scp -vv` to see if there is something in logs?

Comment: I followed your comment but the log record is too long to write here.

Comment: <<<<The last sentence of log record is here>>>>

debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 36
Sink: C0644 0 result_analysis.txt
debug2: channel 0: written 36 to efd 6
result_analysis.txt                                                             100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
Sending file modes: C0644 0 result_analysis2.txt

Comment: You say that scp isn't printing any errors. How do you know that it's failing?

Comment: If you use ssh keys, you don't need expect at all. `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: you see the below comment, the thing is the default time-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout for `expect` is 10 seconds so `expect eof` would wait for at most 10 seconds which may be not enough for many files as you mentioned.

To fix, you can `set timeout -1` before `expect eof` or just `expect -timeout -1 eof`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a while back, but for multiple servers, the list of which would change from night to night. I discovered sometimes scp would ask to add the host to your list of known hosts first, or other messages for which I had to code handling. That could be getting buried in your script.

This is an excerpt of what ultimately worked, if that helps:

```
        expect -c "
                spawn ssh-copy-id -i /x/home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  $USER@$HOST
                expect {
                        \"password:\" {
                                send \"$PASS\n\"
                                expect {
                                        \"expecting.\" { }
                                        timeout {exit 1}
                                        \"again.\" {exit 1}
                                }
                        }
                        \"yes/no)?\" { 
                                send \"yes\n\" 
                                expect \"password:\" {
                                        send \"$PASS\n\"
                                        expect {
                                                \"expecting.\" { }
                                                timeout {exit 1}
                                                \"again.\" {exit 1}
                                        }
                                }
                        }                
                }
```

Comment: So many backslashes. Stick with the heredoc like in the question.